# Screen scraping in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, screen-scraping

This is how i cache web page but i am not getting full page, there is about 30 result in this page and i am getting just 26 results. Please anyone can help me?

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
html = wc.DownloadString("http://www.yellowpages.com/ga/metropcs-store?g=GA&page=1&q=Metropcs+Store").ToString();
```

Yes its end with  if anyone got any solution for this please help me

Comment: Does the string ends with "</html>" ?

Comment: How are you parsing the output?

Comment: btw, try the [YP API](http://developer.yp.com/api/Listings%2520Endpoints/Search-60)

Comment: As long as given link returns antibot page, I think you should try yp API as suggested.

Comment: you have any exaMPLE CODE FOR YP API ?

Answer (score 0):

The Code that you provided is working correctly. means The html returned contains exactly 30 items. There may be some issue with the parsing technique that you are following. When i checked i found a slight difference in the css class applied for the 28th 29th and 30th item. That may be causing the issue

Comment: i dont think there is any difference in css i am using this as my parsing thing  MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(html1, @"(?<=<span class=""street-address""[^>]*>).*?(?=</span>)", RegexOptions.Singleline); please help me in this

Comment: The items i to 27  the css class for one of the div is "rank pin". For 28, 29 and 30 it is just "rank". Even visual difference is there (pls check the redendered page), The last three items does not have backgound for index numbers

Comment: i am not using that div for rank pin i am using this <span class="street-address">
4864 Jimmy Carter Blvd,
</span>
so it doesn't matter is css of anyother change i am extracting data like this                                                    MatchCollection m2 =Regex.Matches(html1, @"(?<=<span class=""street-address""[^>]*>).*?(?=</span>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);                  foreach (Match m in m2)
                {
                    Response.Write(m.ToString() + "<br />");

                }

Comment: "street-address" is missing in some of the items for eg: 11th item

Comment: For the 11th, 28th, 29th and 30th there is no Street-address. Thats why you are getting 26 results. But actually In the Html returned from the yellowpages there are 30 records

Comment: so what should i do now any solution

Comment: actually what all data do you want to find out from that page? Just the street is enough means your current code will do.

Comment: i need all 30 address name number zip code and if some of them have no address then its ok it should skip and fetch the next record is there any way you can help on this

Comment: Your Current parsing logic is not working? The same logic that you put above in the comments should work. If its not working then tell what is the error/issue  that you are getting

Comment: hmm that code is good no error but not getting required results thats the main problem http://www.yellowpages.com/ga/metropcs-store?g=GA&page=1&q=Metropcs+Store i need all the 30 records and thats waht i am not getting it can you solve it if you can please provide me a code